# ISBN final digit finder

Tags: python, isbn

I am working in python 3 and I am making a program that will take in a 10 digit ISBN Number and applying a method to it to find the 11th number.

Here is my current code

```
ISBN=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

while len(ISBN)!= 10:

    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    ISBN=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
    continue


else:

    Digit1=int(ISBN[0])*11
    Digit2=int(ISBN[1])*10
    Digit3=int(ISBN[2])*9
    Digit4=int(ISBN[3])*8
    Digit5=int(ISBN[4])*7
    Digit6=int(ISBN[5])*6
    Digit7=int(ISBN[6])*5
    Digit8=int(ISBN[7])*4
    Digit9=int(ISBN[8])*3
    Digit10=int(ISBN[9])*2
    Sum=(Digit1+Digit2+Digit3+Digit4+Digit5+Digit6+Digit7+Digit8+Digit9+Digit10)
    Mod=Sum%11
    Digit11=11-Mod
    if Digit11==10:
       Digit11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11)
    print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + ISBNNumber)
```

I want to create some kind of loop so that the number after "Digit" for the variable name increases starting from 1 (or zero if it makes life easier), the number in the square brackets increases starting from 0 and the multiplication number to decrease from 11 to 2.

Is there any way of doing this code in a more efficient way?

Comment: Yes, this code is a good candidate for a list comprehension: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html (plus summing function).

Comment: Why wouldn't you use an array for `Digit`?

Comment: @user2197058: Please don't destroy your questions -- that removes value from the answers people spent time working on.

Comment: "I need it to be deleted" meaning, it's a homework assignment, and I don't want my teacher to know I used Stack Overflow?

Comment: @user2197058: it's not yours to delete-- the license you agreed to is [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  In any case, to avoid an edit war, I've flagged this question for moderator intervention.

Comment: @user2197058: you probably don't want to thank me.  I think people who ask for others' assistance in covering up their cheating shouldn't receive it.  The only reason I'm not fixing your vandalism again myself is that it's considered poor form for trusted users to get into an edit war.

Comment: Im sorry, I wasnt aware that i was not allowed to do this. It was a mistake i made

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do what you want.

```
def get_isbn_number(isbn):
    digits = [(11 - i) * num for i, num in enumerate(map(int, list(isbn)))]
    digit_11 = 11 - (sum(digits) % 11)
    if digit_11 == 10:
        digit_11 = 'X'    
    digits.append(digit_11)
    isbn_number = "".join(map(str, digits))
    return isbn_number
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
>>> print(get_isbn_number('2345432681'))
22303640281810242428
>>> print(get_isbn_number('2345432680'))
2230364028181024240X
```

Explanation of second line:

```
digits = [(11 - i) * num for i, num in enumerate(map(int, list(isbn)))]
```

Could be written out like:

```
isbn_letters = list(isbn) # turn a string into a list of characters
isbn_numbers = map(int, isbn_letters) # run the function int() on each of the items in the list
digits = [] # empty list to hold the digits
for i, num in enumerate(isbn_numbers): # loop over the numbers - i is a 0 based counter you get for free when using enumerate
    digits.append((11 - i) * num) # If you notice the pattern, if you subtract the counter value (starting at 0) from 11 then you get your desired multiplier
```

Terms you should look up to understand the one line version of the code:
[map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map),
[enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate),
[list conprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: What does the second line mean? Can you please explain it

Answer (score 0):

```
ISBN=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')) # Ensuring ISBN is an integer

while len(ISBN)!= 10:

    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    ISBN=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
    continue

else:
    Sum = 0
    for i in range(len(ISBN)):
        Sum += ISBN[i]
    Mod=Sum%11
    Digit11=11-Mod
    if Digit11==10:
       Digit11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11)
    print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + ISBNNumber)
```