# How to use Pascal string in equation

Tags: pascal, freepascal, isbn

I have a little problem. I have written a program which asks for user for a code which contains 11 digits. I defined it as string but now I would like to use every digit from this code individually and make an equation.

for example if code is `37605030299` i need to do equation:

```
(1*3 + 2*7 + 3*6 + 4*0 + 5*5 + 6*0 + 7*3 + 8*0 + 9*2 + 1*9) / 11
```

and find out what's the MOD.

This is a calculation for an ISBN check digit.

Comment: You can't multiply strings (`N1 * 1` when `N1` is a string or Char), and you can't do modulo (`mod`) operations on a string either. Your question is totally unclear, since neither thing you're asking about doing is even remotely possible. You have to convert to some sort of number in order to multiply or mod it. In addition, your question can be reduced to `if N11 = (something) then DoThis else DoThat` - there's no need for the second `(N1*1 + N2*2...)` at all. You need to [edit] your question and make it clear what you're trying to do - what you've asked is impossible. Is this a CheckDigit?

Comment: This problem just seems strikingly similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558881/isbn-final-digit-finder/15559059#15559059

Comment: I edited it, can u understand my problem now?

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same program, but how can I do the same in pascal??? like: Digit1=int(ISBN[1])*11 ???

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop instead. (I'm only showing the total value and check digit calculation - you need to get the user input first into a variable named `UserISBN` yourself.)

```
function AddCheckDigit(const UserISBN: string): string;    
var
  i, Sum: Integer;
  CheckDigit: Integer;
  LastCharValue: string;
begin
  Assert(Length(UserISBN) = 10, 'Invalid ISBN number.');
  Sum := 0;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    Sum := Sum + (Ord(UserISBN[i]) * i);

  { Calculate the check digit }
  CheckDigit := 11 - (Sum mod 11);

  { Determine check digit character value }
  if CheckDigit = 10 then
    LastCharValue := 'X'
  else
    LastCharValue := IntToStr(CheckDigit);

  { Add to string for full ISBN Number }
  Result := UserISBN + LastCharValue;
end;
```

Comment: @Tutompita: The edit you suggested wasn't the proper one, but your input prompted me to improve the answer. Thanks. :-)