# Pascal string use (correct Python example)

Tags: python, string, pascal, freepascal

I have this task in which I ask user to input 11 digit code(string).

1)
Lets say the user input code is 37605030299 for example.

2)
Then I need to check if the last number matches. This is how you get the last number: 
nr11 = (nr1*1 + nr2*2 + nr3*3 + nr4*4 + nr5*5 + nr6*6 + nr7*7 + nr8*8 + nr9*9 + nr10*1) mod 11

3)
This is what I wrote:

```
var  C, nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5, nr6, nr7, nr8, nr9, nr10, nr11: string;

begin

nr1:=(copy(C, 1, 1));  
nr2:=(copy(C, 2, 1));
nr3:=(copy(C, 3, 1));
nr4:=(copy(C, 4, 1));
nr5:=(copy(C, 5, 1));
nr6:=(copy(C, 6, 1));
nr7:=(copy(C, 7, 1));
nr8:=(copy(C, 8, 1));
nr9:=(copy(C, 9, 1));
nr10:=(copy(C, 10, 1));
nr11:=(copy(C, 11, 1));   

writeln('Enter the code which contains 11 digits:');
 readln(C);

 if nr11 = (nr1*1 + nr2*2 + nr3*3 + nr4*4 + nr5*5 + nr6*6 + nr7*7 + nr8*8 + nr9*9 + nr10*1) mod 11 then
  begin
   writeln('The code is correct!');
  end

else
 if nr11 <> (nr1*1 + nr2*2 + nr3*3 + nr4*4 + nr5*5 + nr6*6 + nr7*7 + nr8*8 + nr9*9 + nr10*1) mod 11
  begin
   writeln('The code is incorrect!');
  end;

  readln();
end.
```

This doesn't work because I know that u can't use strings in equations like I do, but would it work? I'm just learning Pascal, sorry if this looks too dumb.

This UI code should be correct. Checking:

1*3 + 2*7 + 3*6 + 4*0 + 5*5 + 6*0 + 7*3 + 8*0 + 9*2 + 1*9 = 108

108/11 ~ 9,8

9*11 = 99

108-99 = 9 (the answer is 9, so last digit must be 9, last digit is 9 which shows that the code is correct)

If you didn't understand what I tried to do then I found one example in python which should be correct:

```
def checkIDCode(code):
    if len(code) != 11 or not code.isdigit():
            return False

    c = map(int,code)
    w1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]
    w2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3]

    s1 = sum(map(lambda x,y: x*y, c[:-1], w1))%11
    s2 = (sum(map(lambda x,y: x*y, c[:-1], w2))%11)%10

    return s1 == c[-1] or s1 == 10 and s2 == c[-1]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581551/how-to-use-pascal-string-in-equation for some clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you copy stuff from C when C is empty. You should place readln(C) before you try to access it's elements:

```
writeln('Enter the code which contains 11 digits:');
readln(C);

nr1:=...
nr2:=...
```

The second thing is that if the values are only 1 char, you can access it by index:

```
nr1:= C[1];
nr2:= C[2];
...
```

To convert string to integer, you have to include sysutils to use StrToInt function: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strtoint.html

Another way (char by char) is to calculate the difference between the char value and 48 (which is ASCII code for '0')

Sample code:

```
uses sysutils;
var  C:string
     nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5, nr6, nr7, nr8, nr9, nr10, nr11: integer;

begin
readln(C);
nr1:=strtoint(C[1]);
nr2:=strtoint(C[2]);
nr3:=strtoint(C[3]);
.
.
.
if nr11 = (nr1*1 + nr2*2 + nr3*3 + nr4*4 + nr5*5 + nr6*6 + nr7*7 + nr8*8 + nr9*9 + nr10*1) mod 11 then
   writeln('The code is correct!') 
   //if you skip the begin/end statements, only the next statement 
   //is executed in loops/if statements
else writeln('Not correct'); //notice that I didn't use ELSE IF but ELSE
readln; 
//in Pascal you can skip the parathenses if you don't pass arguments to the function
end.
```

Comment: when i try to
 nr1:=strtoint(C[1]) 
it says: Error: Incompatible types: got "LongInt" expected "ShortString"

Comment: @Fr0f0 nr1, nr2, ... should be integers. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I have tried to figure it out so long time. Thank you from my heart!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like ISBN. To calculate the check digit I suggest the following.

```
function DigitToInt(const c: Char): Integer;
begin
  if (c<'0') or (c>'9') then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid input');
  Result := ord(c)-ord('0');
end;
```

This converts a single character in the range '0' to '9' to the corresponding integer value.

```
function CheckDigit(const s: string): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Length(s)<>11 then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid input');
  Result := 0;
  for i := 1 to 10 do
    inc(Result, DigitToInt(s[i])*i);
  Result := Result mod 11;
end;
```

This calculates the check digit for an 11 digit code.

To compare the actual check digit with the calculated check digit you would write:

```
if CheckDigit(code) <> DigitToInt(code[11]) then
  .... handle error
```

Comment: It says, identifier raise, result and digittoint not found

Comment: Delphi. The code will work fine in fpc too. The code in the answer you accepted is much more complex. Why declare all those variables. My code doesn't need that at all.