# how to not give any output in python

Tags: python, isbn

I am working on school problem where they give the equation for identifying if ISBN number is valid and give us ten inputs(numbers) and a stop input at the end.

This was my code:

```
a=str(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
e=int(input())
f=int(input())
g=int(input())
h=int(input())
i=int(input())
j=int(input())
u=input() #this is where stop is usually at
if j==int((int(a)+(2*b)+(3*c)+(4*d)+(5*e)+(6*f)+(7*g)+(8*h)+(9*i))%11):
    print("OK")
elif j!=int((int(a)+(2*b)+(3*c)+(4*d)+(5*e)+(6*f)+(7*g)+(8*h)+(9*i))%11):
    print("WRONG")
elif a=="stop":
    print("")
```

The last two lines are there because one of the answers was just one line input: "stop". In this case, the code shouldn't give any output but my code doesn't work and since there is only one input, it gives out an EOF on second line of the code. How can I make this work?

Comment: Fix your indentation please!

Comment: Try to work through the logic with a pencil and paper then translate that to your code.  You really need to figure out your homework yourself.

Comment: Why aren't you using prompts with the [input function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISBN final digit finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558881/isbn-final-digit-finder)

Answer (score 0):

`j` is either equal to `int((int(a)+(2*b)+(3*c)+(4*d)+(5*e)+(6*f)+(7*g)+(8*h)+(9*i))%11)` (which btw you don't have to compute twice...), or not. So `elif a=="stop":` is never reached. Test for `a=="stop"` first thing.

Comment: I tried that, but its still giving me eof at line 2

Comment: FIRST thing: `a=str(input())` then test for `a=="stop"` immediately (i.e at line 2)

Comment: tried it and now its giving me eof at line 3 instead of 2

Comment: usually it is at variable u